# How to show that $\frac {q + \frac {1}{2}}{p - \frac {1}{2}} > \sum_{i = p}^q\frac {1}{i}$ if $q\ge p > 0?$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

How to show that : $$\frac{2q+1}{2p-1}>\sum_{i=p}^q\frac{1}{i}$$ if $q\ge p>0$

Comment: Are you sure it is not missing a $\log$ in the LHS?

Comment: And what if he was there log?

Comment: It is a much stronger inequality that appears, for instance, in the proof of the Polya-Vinogradov inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\dfrac{1}{i} \le \dfrac{1}{p}$ for $p \le i \le q$, and $0 < q-(p-1) < q+\frac{1}{2}$, and $p > p - \frac{1}{2} > 0$, we have

$\displaystyle\sum_{i = p}^{q}\dfrac{1}{i} \le \sum_{i = p}^{q}\dfrac{1}{p} = \dfrac{q-(p-1)}{p} < \dfrac{q+\frac{1}{2}}{p-\frac{1}{2}}$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x\in (0,2)$ we have:
$$\log\frac{1+x/2}{1-x/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{4^k(2k+1)}>x,$$
hence:
$$\sum_{i=p}^{q}\frac{1}{i}<\sum_{i=p}^{q}\log\frac{2i+1}{2i-1}=\log\frac{2q+1}{2p-1},$$
establishing a much stronger inequality - that appears, for instance, in the proof of the Polya-Vinogradov inequality.